# Change Android quicksshd to listen to the public ip

Tags: android, networking, ssh

I would like to ssh to my android phone via internet. Is it possible?

I have a non-rooted sony xperia mini running Quicksshd server. Quicksshd listens private ip 10.x.x.x that can not be changed. However, when I go to www.whatismyip.com the phone's public ip is 193.x.x.x. So, can I make quicksshd listen to that ip or is there another way to connect to the phone?

Answer (score 1):

Cellular data connections are invariably behind at least one layer of NAT gateways - there is no way to access the phone from the 'outside' world, unless the phone establishes the connection itself.